# efficiently computing parafac / CP product in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

This question focuses on numpy.

I have a set of matrices which all share the same number of columns and have different number of rows. Let's call them A, B, C, D, etc  and let their dimensions be IaxK IbxK, IcxK, etc

What I want is to efficiently compute the IaxIbxIc... tensor P defined as follow:
P(ia,ib,ic,id,ie,...)=\sum_k A(ia,k)B(ib,k)C(ic,k)...

So if I have two factors, I end up with simple matrix product.

Of course I can compute this "by hand" through outer products, something like:

```
    def parafac(factors,components=None):
        ndims = len(factors)
        ncomponents = factors[0].shape[1]
        total_result=array([])
        if components is None:
            components=range(ncomponents)

        for k in components:
            #for each component (to save memory)
            result = array([])
            for dim in range(ndims-1,-1,-1):
                #Augments model with next dimension
                current_dim_slice=[slice(None,None,None)]
                current_dim_slice.extend([None]*(ndims-dim-1))
                current_dim_slice.append(k)
                if result.size:
                    result = factors[dim].__getitem__(tuple(current_dim_slice))*result[None,...]
                else:
                    result = factors[dim].__getitem__(tuple(current_dim_slice))
            if total_result.size:
                total_result+=result
            else:
                total_result=result
        return total_result
```

Still, I would like something much more computationally efficient, like relying on builtin numpy functions, but I cannot find relevant functions, can someone help me ?

Cheers, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you all very much for your answers, I've spent the day on this and I eventually found the solution, so I post it here for the record

This solution requires numpy 1.6 and makes use of einsum, which is
powerful voodoo magic

basically, if you had factor=[A,B,C,D] with A,B,C and D matrices with
the same number of columns, then you would compute the parafac model using:

```
import numpy
P=numpy.einsum('az,bz,cz,dz->abcd',A,B,C,D)
```

so, one line!

In the general case, I end up with this:

```
def parafac(factors):
    ndims = len(factors)
    request=''
    for temp_dim in range(ndims):
        request+=string.lowercase[temp_dim]+'z,'
    request=request[:-1]+'->'+string.lowercase[:ndims]
    return einsum(request,*factors)
```

Comment: It is indeed powerful voodoo, and even runs about twice as fast as what I produced

Comment: Nice.  Have you compared the speed of this version with your original?  I tried both using four arrays with shapes (10,3), (24,3), (15,3) and (75,3).  Your original version takes about 2ms, and the version using `einsum` takes about 7.5ms.

Comment: It looks like einsum does benefit from multicore architectures whereas my original stuff did not. Moreover, I've experimentally noticed that it did scale up better (true cases of interest are rather for matrices of some thousands lines and something like 50 columns). I'll try this out

Comment: @antoine do you know how to change it for non-negativitiy constraint?

Comment: Great answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Having in mind that outer product is Kronecker product in disguise your problem should be solved by this simple functions:

```
def outer(vectors):
    shape=[v.shape[0] for v in vectors]
    return reduce(np.kron, vectors).reshape(shape)
def cp2Tensor(l,A):
    terms=[]    
    for r in xrange(A[0].shape[1]):
        term=l[r]*outer([A[n][:,r] for n in xrange(len(A))])
        terms.append(term)
    return sum(terms)
```

cp2Tensor takes list of real numbers and list of matrices.

Edited after comment by Jaime.

Comment: Doesn't work... If you apply it to 2 vectors of sizes (5,8) and (4,8), you get a new one of (20, 64) that you then try to reshape to (5,4)... At best, you are missing the summation step before reshaping, although I am not quite sure that the result will be what was asked

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the following works. First a worked out example of what's going on...

```
a = np.random.rand(5, 8)
b = np.random.rand(4, 8)
c = np.random.rand(3, 8)
ret = np.ones(5,4,3,8)
ret *= a.reshape(5,1,1,8)
ret *= b.reshape(1,4,1,8)
ret *= c.reshape(1,1,3,8)
ret = ret.sum(axis=-1)
```

And a full function

```
def tensor(elems) :
    cols = elems[0].shape[-1]
    n_elems = len(elems)
    ret = np.ones(tuple([j.shape[0] for j in elems] + [cols]))
    for j,el in enumerate(elems) :
        ret *= el.reshape((1,) * j + (el.shape[0],) +
                          (1,) * (len(elems) - j - 1) + (cols,))
    return ret.sum(axis=-1)
```